# append to a parent span class only using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to generate dynamic forms using jquery.

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document.body).delegate('#AddFeature', 'click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var htm = "";
        htm += "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' name='module[][]' placeholder='Enter Feature'/>";
        $('#AddFeatureSpace').append(htm);
    });

    $(document.body).delegate('#AddModule', 'click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var htm = '';
        htm += "<input type='text' name='module[]' placeholder='Enter Module'/>";
        htm += "<span id='AddFeatureSpace'></span><a href='#' id='AddFeature'>Add Feature</a><br/>";
        $('#AddModuleSpace').append(htm);
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='text' name='module[]' placeholder='Enter Module' />
<span id="AddFeatureSpace"></span><a href='#' id='AddFeature'>Add Feature</a>
<br />
<a href='#' id="AddModule">Add Module</a>
<div id="AddModuleSpace">
</div>
</form>
```

The first time it adds very good when i click add feature.
But when i try to add module and then add feature under it, it adds to the first module.
I know the reason for this as they have the same id.
I need to append them to the parent span instead of a different span.

Comment: how do i add the features to the parent module only

Comment: like this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/xuvrm/. But you really need to rewrite your code totally.

Comment: It's worth to see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/7qB4m/) I've created it `;)`. I also explain about it at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your question is, but you should use classes rather than IDs if you're requiring multiple elements with the same identifier. [IDs must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

```
<span class="AddFeatureSpace"></span>
<a href='#' class='AddFeature'>Add Feature</a><br/>
<a href='#' class="AddModule">Add Module</a>
<div class="AddModuleSpace"></div>
```

```
$(document.body).delegate('.AddModule', 'click', function(event) { ... });
// Etc...
```

Also you really shouldn't use `&nbsp;` for padding - use CSS instead.

> how do i add the features to the parent module only

You can reference an element's parent using [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: I will be having n features and n modules, how do i know that i am clicking on this particular class

Comment: You can reference the element you've clicked on using `$(this)`. Check out http://try.jquery.com for an interactive jQuery tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form method='post'>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document.body).delegate('#AddFeature', 'click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var htm="";
htm+="<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' 
name='module[][]' placeholder='Enter Feature'/>";
$('#AddFeatureSpace').append(htm);
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document.body).delegate('#AddModule', 'click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var htm='';
htm+="<input type='text' name='module[]' placeholder='Enter Module'/>";
htm += "<span id='AddFeatureSpace'></span><a href='#' id='AddFeature'>Add Feature</a>        
<br/>";
$('#AddModuleSpace').parent().append(htm);
});
</script>
<input type='text' name='module[]' placeholder='Enter Module'/>
<span id="AddFeatureSpace"></span>
<a href='#' id='AddFeature'>Add Feature</a><br/>
<a href='#' id="AddModule">Add Module</a>
<span id="AddModuleSpace"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly, but functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WPkCD/1/)

HTML

```
<form method='post' id="Modules">
    <input type='text' name='module[]' placeholder='Enter Module' />
    <div class="AddFeatureSpace"> 
        <a href='#' class='AddFeature'>Add Feature</a>

    </div> 

    <a href='#' class="AddModule">Add Module</a>
    <div class="AddModuleSpace"></div>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('#Modules')
    .on('click', '.AddFeature', function () {
    $(this).closest('.AddFeatureSpace').append($('<input type="text" name="module[][]" placeholder="Enter Feature"/>'));
})
    .on('click', '.AddModule', function () {
    var el = '<input type="text" name="module[]" placeholder="Enter Module"/>' +
        '<span class="AddFeatureSpace">' +
        '<a href="#" class="AddFeature">Add Feature</a>' +
        '</span>';
    $(this).siblings('.AddModuleSpace').append($(el));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/7qB4m/)**</kbd>

### HTML

It's good idea to have our HTML better:

```
<form method='post'>

    <div class="modules">
        <!-- modules container -->
    </div>

    <a href='#' id="AddModule">Add Module</a>
</form>


<!-- module template -->
<div class="module raw">
    <input type='text' name='module[]' placeholder='Enter Module' />

    <a href='#' id='AddFeature'>Add Feature</a>

    <div class="features">
        <!-- features container -->
    </div>

    <hr />
</div>

<!-- feature template -->
<div class="feature raw">
    <input type="text" name="module[][]" placeholder="placeholder" />
</div>
```

---

### CSS

We'll hidden our `.raw` elements:

```
.raw { display: none; }
```

---

### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#AddFeature', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // clone a raw feature
        $('.feature.raw').clone()

        // remove class raw from it
        .removeClass('raw')

        // and append it to the current module
        .appendTo($(this).closest('.module').find('.features'));
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#AddModule', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // clone a raw module
        $('.module.raw').clone()

        // remove class raw from it
        .removeClass('raw')

        // and append it to the modules container
        .appendTo('.modules');
    });
});
```

---

### ScreenShot

[image]

---

- `[!]` Don't forget to check the [FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/7qB4m/).